# MYSQL, Como fazer SELECT sem agrupar valores idênticos do WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa Tarde

```
SELECT id, descricao FROM Produtos WHERE id IN ('1','1','2', '3','3');
```

Mas o resultado fica

> ```
> id / descricao
> 1 / Caneta
> 2 / Lapis
> 3 / Borracha
> ```

Eu queria que ficasse conforme a tabela abaixo

> ```
> id / descricao
> 1 / Caneta
> 1 / Caneta
> 2 / Lapis
> 3 / Borracha
> 3 / Borracha
> ```

Comment: você vai usar esse retorno com alguma linguagem? acredito que seja mais fácil fazer isso lá...

Comment: Não tenho certeza se funciona, mas acho vc pode criar uma variável do tipo lista, preencher com os valores da clausula "IN" e usar um "WHILE" para para fazer o select em cima de cada um dos itens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Amigo!
Acredito que você esteja precisando utilizar o UNION e estruturar seu SELECT conforme exemplo abaixo:

**Instrução MySQL**

```
SELECT id, descricao FROM Produtos WHERE id IN (1) UNION
SELECT id, descricao FROM Produtos WHERE id IN (1)
```

Isso fará com que o SELECT seja realizado de forma individual e unificada ao ser executado.

Acredito que essa seja uma alternativa.
Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços,